# HTML5 Canvas replace to <div>

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, drawimage

I'm trying replace HTML5 Canvas to simple `<div>`
But I don't know how to replace this line:

```
ctx.drawImage(tileImg[drawTile],xpos,ypos);
```

Maybe anyone have idea how to replace this into `<div>`?

example : http://jsfiddle.net/HDpMW/5/ (this code from glacialflame.com)

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'Simple HTML'?

Comment: Why do you think a div should know to draw arbitrary images?

Comment: What do you mean "replace to div?"

Comment: This example work when browser support Canvas element.
no, I don't think <div> can draw images, but images can draw in <div> element(Something like with CSS).
Sorry for "Simple HTML" and sorry for my English language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `<img>` elements, and append them dynamically like this: http://jsfiddle.net/HDpMW/6/

```
var elem = document.createElement('img');
elem.src = tileDict[drawTile];
elem.style.position = 'absolute';
elem.style.left = xpos + 'px';
elem.style.top = ypos + 'px';
ctx.appendChild(elem);
```